# Meteor: How do you preserve dom manipulations when page refreshes or another page location?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have an infinite scroll that adds new elements (links), when I navigate to the link and go back in my browser, I am back to the first page of results and not the expansive elements that were added as a result of my previous scrolling action.

Comment: One of the benefits of using meteor is eliminating the need to do page refreshing or navigation. You can try using session/querystring variables to help in this behavior if you require it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it all wrong! Need to do it the meteor way.

You simply grow the number of documents on the client side by using `Deps.autorun()` and changing the page number `Session.set('currentPage');`

main.js

```
//when scrollbar reaches end of page, just change the 'currentPage' session variable to 'grow' the list template
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
var nowPage = Session.get('pageNumber');
Session.set('pageNumber', parseInt(nowPage) + 1);
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

client/subscription.js

```
Deps.autorun(function(){
  Meteor.subscribe('huge-list', Session.get('currentPage'); //whenever currentPage changes, so will your subscription if you set up your publish() on the server side;
});
```

server/publication.js

```
Meteor.publish('huge-list', function(page){ //when session changes on client, this changes
return Requests.find({}, {limit:page});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way would be to save the state of your scroll, then re-apply your DOM manipulations after Meteor has rendered your templates.

For example, something like this:

```
Template.my_template.rendered = function() {
    $('#my-scrolling-element').scroll(function(e) {scrollPosition = e.target.scrollTop()})

    if(scrollPosition) {
        $('#my-scrolling-element').scrollTo(scrollPosition);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about doing this too but now I am thinking of doing the following. I simply "grow" the number of documents available in the collection from the subscription. so when they come back to this page, it will show however number of documents were available before and then scroll the user down to the position they were at from the Session value